# how to print quote character in awk

Tags: shell-script, awk, gawk

I have a file `str.txt` with the following sample records.

```
31,2713810299,1,11-Aug-15 19:52:10
32,2713810833,1,11-Aug-15 21:36:18
```

Now I want to print output with awk as below.

```
cat str.txt|awk -F, '{print substr("$4",1,9)}' -
```

The output should be:

```
'11-Aug-15' 
'11-Aug-15'
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

a single quote would be `\x27`

```
awk -F, '{print "\x27"substr($4,1,9)"\x27" }'
```

Comment: Use octal `\047` for `'`, not hex `\x27`. See http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote.

Comment: \x22 for double quote (in case you need it)

Answer (score 7):

POSIXly:

```
awk -F'[ ,]' -v q="'" '{print q$4q}' <file
```

Comment: brilliant and elegant

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach, for POSIX Awk:

```
awk -F'[, ]' '{printf "\047%s\047\n", $4}' file
'11-Aug-15'
'11-Aug-15'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` command like this:

```
cat str.txt|awk -F, '{print substr($4,1,9)}' -
```

To get following output:

```
11-Aug-15
11-Aug-15
```

If single quotes requires at the start and end of lines then:

```
cat str.txt|awk -F, '{printf "\047%s\047\n",substr($4,1,9)}' -
```

To get following output:

```
'11-Aug-15'
'11-Aug-15'
```

Comment: No single quotes are printed, which the question specifies...

Comment: @jasonwryan: Please check answer updated as per requirement.